# Objective-C Returning Autoreleased Copies

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copy, autorelease

A strange issue I've come across trying to understand Apple's Memory Management standards. Lets say I have a method that returns a copy without letting the user know that it is a copy.

```
+(Point2D*) Add:(Point2D*)a To:(Point2D*)b
{
        Point2D * newPoint = [a copy];
        [newPoint Add:b]; // Actually perform the arithmetic.
        return [newPoint autorelease];
}
```

The problem is that Xcode's Analyze function flags this as an object being sent too many -autorelease calls. I'm assuming this is because -copy implicitly assumes that you are taking ownership, and thus the possibility of +0 retain count is likely. But I'm not entirely sure.

Xcode's Analyze Information

```
+(Point2D*) Add:(Point2D*)a To:(Point2D*)b
{
        Point2D * newPoint = [a copy]; // <- 1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count.
        [newPoint Add:b];
        return [newPoint autorelease]; // <- 2. Object sent -autorelease method.
                                       // <- 3. Object returned to caller with a +0 retain count.
                                       // <- 4. Object over -autoreleased: object was sent -autorelease but the object has zero (locally visible) retain counts.
}
```

Any tips or hints on why this is happening? Unless I'm missing something, the code should work fine because the autorelease wont trigger until a safe time (i.e. it works kind of like a convenience constructor, user has time to retain.)

As per request, -copyWithZone: would be implemented as such:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
        return [[Point2D allocWithZone:zone] initX:x Y:y Z:z];
}
```

Comment: Your code looks right. You should be autoreleasing the copy. What version of Xcode are you using? On mine, I can't even name a type called "Point", because it conflicts with the one in QuickTime: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTRef_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003454-GlobalQuickTimeAPITypes-Point

Comment: You're correct, I used a general case and simply named it Point arbitrarily. In my code it occurs in my Matrix3x3, Matrix4x4, Vector3, Vector4 classes. I was trying to cite a general case for the purposes of this question. - I have edited the question to use Point2D to avoid further confusion.
Also, I am using Xcode 4.2 Build: 4C199

Comment: It must be a bug in your Xcode. Try Xcode 4.3

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to assume it's a bug. I cannot do more to test unfortunately, as I'm running Snow Leopard and cannot upgrade to 4.3 - :/ But the fact that I'm hearing consistently that this is what I'm supposed to be doing and seeing several other examples is enough. If anyone can confirm that the code doesn't analyze improperly on 4.3 I'll be happy in marking this complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement `-copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone` in your `Point` class correctly (or at least please copy it here)

Comment: I have edited the original post to include -copyWithZone:, thanks for the quick response! - Note: This does not fix the Analyze problem, as I had -copyWithZone: implemented already. :(

Comment: ah, look: "A subclass version of the copyWithZone: method should send the message to super first, to incorporate its implementation, unless the subclass descends directly from NSObject." (c) NSObject Class Reference from Apple. Try to implement copyWithZone correctly.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Sketch+Accessibility/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008920 Download this sample code and try to look on the copyWithZone implementation (SKTGraphic from NSObject and SKTImage from SKTGraphic)

Comment: Even after changing it, it still Analyzes as a possible Memory Issue. I think it may be an issue with my version of XCode, but I can't upgrade because I use Snow Leopard. :/ Nice catch though, I will implement copyWithZone: properly from now on. (I actually wasn't aware of this issue.)